# Prove that $1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 < n^4$.

Tags: real-analysis, induction, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following: $1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 < n^4$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>1$ by induction. From there, I am to prove that the sum is $< \frac{n^4}{2}$ if $n>2$. My attempt to do so is as follows:

First, we use $n = 2$ as a basis step since $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>1$ which shows that $1^3+2^3 < 2^4 \Rightarrow 9<16$ which is true. Now, for $n+1$, we have $n^3 + (n+1)^3 < n^4 + (n+1)^4$ by the induction hypothesis. By expanding the two binomials, we have
$2n^3+3n^2+3n+1< 2n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$. By simplifying our expression, we are left with
$0<n(2n^3+2n^2+3n+1)$ which would always be true with $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>1$.

I am not sure if this proof would be valid, or if it is logically correct. As for the second part of the question, I would not know where to begin. Could somebody please provide a hint or point out where this goes awry? Any suggestions and/or criticism is welcome.

I am using the textbook *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You go astray at the beginning of the induction step. Your induction hypothesis is that

$$1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3<n^4\;,\tag{1}$$

and you want to show that

$$1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3+(n+1)^3<(n+1)^4\;.$$

In other words, you **don’t** have $n^3+(n+1)^3<n^4+(n+1)^4$ by the induction hypothesis: what you have is that

$$\Big(1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3\Big)+(n+1)^3<n^4+(n+1)^3\;,$$

obtained by adding $(n+1)^3$ to both sides of $(1)$. To complete the induction step, you need to show that $n^4+(n+1)^3\le(n+1)^4$, and what you wrote, though incorrect, shows that you probably can do that just fine.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the error. However, I am a little confused about the $n^4+(n+1)^3 \leq (n+1)^4$ part. How does the $(n+1)$ go from being cubed on the left to being raised to the fourth power on the right?

Comment: @Jamil: It doesn’t really. What you’re proving is that if $n>1$, the sum of the first $n$ cubes is less than $n^4$, that’s all. In the induction step you know that the sum of the first $n+1$ cubes is less than $n^4+(n+1)^3$, and it’s just a matter of algebra to check that this is no more than $(n+1)^4$: you just multiply out both sides.

Comment: I appreciate this explanation very much. Thank you @Brian M. Scott for this concise observation.

Comment: @Jamil: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Since Jamil has already understood what to do,I was wondering if we could prove it by noting that the formula for his series is {n(n+1)/2}^2 and then use induction.

Comment: @rahul: If you have that summation formula, you don’t even need induction: $$\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2 = \frac14n^2(n+1)^2 = \frac14\left(n^4+2n^3+n^2\right) < \frac14\left(4n^4\right) = n^4$$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 6):

As the others have said, you went wrong in the induction step. Here's one way to prove what we want without having to expand the binomials:
\begin{align*}
1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + (n+1)^3 &= \left[1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3 \right] + (n+1)^3 \\
&< n^4 + (n+1)^3 \qquad\text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
&= n(n)^3 + 1(n+1)^3 \\
&< \color{red}{n}\color{blue}{(n+1)^3} \color{red}{+ 1}\color{blue}{(n+1)^3} \\
&= (\color{red}{n+1})\color{blue}{(n+1)^3}  \qquad\text{factor out the common }(n+1)^3 \text{ term} \\
&= (n+1)^4 \\
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Very nice use of factoring @Adriano. Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't quite have the induction hypothesis correct. The hypothesis is that

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < n^4$$

Now the goal is to show that, assuming the hypothesis,

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} k^3 < (n + 1)^4$$

Now we consider the left hand side, getting:

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} k^3 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} k^3 + (n + 1)^3 < n^4 + (n + 1)^3$$

where the inequality uses the hypothesis. So really, your goal reduces to showing that

$$n^4 + (n + 1)^3 < (n + 1)^4$$

Comment: For the summation, I have one question: Is it possible to use $k=1$ if we have that $n > 1$?

Comment: @Jamil_V I don't understand your question. The summation always starts at $k = 1$, regardless of what $n$ is.

Comment: Oh, I see why that happens. Thank you very much; I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part,
suppose you want to show that
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$
for some $c<1$.

As a base,
find an $n$
such that this holds,
i.e., that
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$.

You want this to imply that
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n+1} k^3 < c (n+1)^4
$,
and this will be true if
$(n+1)^3 < c((n+1)^4-n^4)
$.

To see whay this is true,
suppose
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$
and
$(n+1)^3 < c((n+1)^4-n^4)
$.
Adding these inequalities,
we get
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n+1} k^3 < c (n+1)^4
$,
which is what we want.

So, we want to find a $c$ such that
$(n+1)^3 < c((n+1)^4-n^4)
$.

In these types of inequalities,
the value of $c$
usually depends on the
value of $n$,
with the larger values of
providing the
better values of $c$.

For the induction to work,
we need a value of $r$
such that
$(n+1)^4-n^4
> r (n+1)^3
$,
so that
$(n+1)^3 < (1/r)((n+1)^4-n^4)$

I will now show that
any $r < 4$ will work.

I will now get a simple lower bound
for
$(n+1)^4-n^4
$
which will be true for
$n \ge 2$.
This will not be the best bound,
but it will show that,
for any $r < 4$,
for $n$ large enough
we have
$(n+1)^4-n^4
< r (n+1)^3
$.

Since
$(n+1)^3 = n^3+3n^2+3n+1$,

$\begin{align}
(n+1)^4-n^4
&=4n^3+6n^2+4n+1\\
&=4(n^3+(3/2)n^2+n+1/4)\\
&=4(n^3+3n^2+3n+1-(3/2)n^2-2n-(3/4))\\
&=4((n+1)^3-(3/2)(n^2+(4/3)n+(1/2))\\
&=4(n+1)^3(1-(3/2)\frac{n^2+(4/3)n+(1/2)}{(n+1)^3})\\
&>4(n+1)^3(1-(3/2)\frac{n^2+2n+1}{(n+1)^3})\\
&=4n^3(1-\frac{3}{2(n+1)})\\
\end{align}
$

So, if
$r < 4$
and
$4(1-\frac{3}{2(n+1)})
> r
$
(which is the same as
$\frac{3}{2(n+1)} < 4-r$
or
$n > \frac{3}{2(4-r)}-1$),
$(n+1)^4-n^4 > r (n+1)^3$.

For example,
using $r = 3$,
if $n > \frac{3}{2}-1 = \frac12$
(i.e., for all $n$),
$(n+1)^4-n^4 > 3 (n+1)^3$.

Rewrite this inequality
in the form
$(n+1)^3
< \frac{(n+1)^4-n^4}{3} 
$,
or, more generally,
for any $r < 4$,
$(n+1)^3
< \frac{(n+1)^4-n^4}{r} 
$
for
$n > \frac{3}{2(4-r)}-1$.

Suppose,
for some $0 < c < 1$,
we have found an $n$
such that
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$.

Adding the inequality we have just proved,
if $rc \ge 1$,
then

$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n+1} k^3 
&< c n^4+\frac{(n+1)^4-n^4}{r}\\
&= c( n^4+\frac{(n+1)^4-n^4}{rc})\\
&\le c( n^4+((n+1)^4-n^4))\\
&= c(n+1)^4\\
\end{align}
$.

We have therefore show the following:

For real $r$ and $c$
such that
$r < 4$ and $rc \ge 1$,
if there is an $n$ 
such that
$n > \frac{3}{2(4-r)}-1$
and
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$,
then
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$
for all larger $n$.

For the case $r=3$
mentioned earlier,
this becomes:

For any real $c$
such that
$c \ge 1/3$,
if there is an $n$ 
such that
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$,
then
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3 < c n^4
$
for all larger $n$.

Here are the initial values of
$(n, \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3, n^4)$:
$(1, 1, 1), (2, 9, 16)
(3, 36, 81), (4, 80, 256)$.

Since $3\cdot 80 < 256$,
$n=4$ works.
So,
for $n \ge 4$,
$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k^3
< \dfrac{n^4}{3}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. 
Assuming $n$ is even, (by making a little bit change, it will fit odd too)

$$ 1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + (n-1)^3 + n^3 $$ 
$$< $$
$$ (n/2)^3 + (n/2)^3 + \dots + n^3 + n^3 $$
$$ < $$
$$ (n/2)*(n/2)^3 + (n/2)*n^3 = n^4/16 + n^4/2 = \frac{9}{16}n^4$$
$$ < $$
$$ n^4$$